# How to send http request in headers?

Tags: java, http, url

I wanted to build a small application that would get weather data by sending a URL request to weatherapi.com. However, I ran into a problem. Here is my code:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

public class WeatherService {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Properties mavenProperties = new Properties();
        InputStream propertiesStream = WeatherService.class.getResourceAsStream("/maven.properties");
        mavenProperties.load(propertiesStream);

        final String API_KEY =  mavenProperties.getProperty("api.key");

        SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        try (SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket("api.weatherapi.com", 443)) {
            socket.startHandshake();
            Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            w.write("GET /v1/current.json HTTP/1.1\r\n");
            w.write("Host: api.weatherapi.com\r\n");
            w.write("Key: " + API_KEY + "\r\n");
            w.write("q: London\r\n");
            w.write("\r\n");
            w.flush();
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
            int b;
            while ((b = in.read()) != -1)
                System.out.write(b);
        }
    }
}
```

I passed the API key through the header, but I can't pass the city data the same way.
Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

3b
{"error":{"code":1003,"message":"Parameter q is missing."}}
0
```

Comment: because that is a query parameter not a header.  Why are you not using an HTTP client library instead of raw sockets?

Comment: Also, is there a specific reason not to use a proper http client like the [`HttClient` that comes with java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html)?

Comment: Even more, weatherapi provides a Java SDK.

Comment: Yes, it could be done using the built-in HTTP library. But I had to do it this way (SOW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
w.write("GET /v1/current.json?q=London HTTP/1.1\r\n");
```

Btw: In HTTP the headers are separated from the body payload by a blank line. In your current code „q“ is an additional header.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's strange that I've tried this before and it didn't work. But now it seems to work